# Read from a file into a single block of memory using C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, file-io, ifstream, getline

I have an ASCII file which contains only a single line. I would like to load the whole line into a `std::string` object. While doing this, I want the whole char array to be placed into a single contiguous memory block. What is the best way of doing this?

Currently, I read the whole file as follows:

```
std::ifstream t(fname);
std::string pstr;

t.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
pstr.reserve(t.tellg());
t.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

pstr.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

If I do in the following way, will the string be placed in a single memory block, too?

```
std::ifstream t(fname);
std::string pstr;
std::getline(t, pstr);
```

If both ways gives the desired feature, which one should be preferred?

Comment: If you are *sure* the file only contains a single unbroken line, then a single call to `std::getline` should work fine. *However* it might not be as effective since it will extend the string dynamically while reading and checking for the end of the line (or file).

Comment: Oh and by the way, you should use `pstr.resize(r.tellg())` instead of `reserve`. While `reserve` allocates memory, it doesn't actually change the size of the string.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if `std::getline` does this and it extends the string dynamically (as you stated), this means that it must allocate contiguous memory blocks. However this feature is not guaranteed, because the dynamically allocated blocks may not be contiguous. Doesn't it still need to allocate a single memory block with enough size?

Comment: But it doesn't *know* the "enough size" from the beginning. It can only read one character at a time, and reallocate the data for each and every character it reads. In the end the string will still be a single contiguous allocated block, but it might have done several allocate/copy/free iterations before it's done.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh, ok. At the end, what it gives is in a single memory. But there are many middle steps. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I do in the following way, will the string be placed in a single memory block, too?

Yes, both methods will do that.

> If both ways gives the desired feature, which one should be preferred?

The 1st one should be preferred to avoid recurring (re-)allocation of the targeted `std::string`. Using a `std::back_inserter` would be more idiomatic though.

Comment: so, `getline` first counts how many chars there are in a line. then allocates memory with that size and does the read. It does not read with a fixed size(let's assume 256 chars) until newline char is reached. Is this correct? Or is there another way of providing this feature which `getline` uses and I don't know?

Comment: @Shnkc _"so, getline first counts how many chars there are in a line."_ No, it reads char by char, until a `'\n'` or whatever delimiter is given, and adds these to the string. Thus a lot of reallocations may occur.

Comment: If it reads one by one, can it guarantee to place all chars into a single memory block? This was the main point in my question. Then, the first method provides the desired feature, not the second one with `getline`.

Comment: Comments to the question clarify how `getline` provides this functionality, although it does many reallocations.